# How do I put emoji over the text in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, emoji

I have a line of numbers as icons `<i>1</i><i>2</i><i>3</i><i>4</i>` and I'm trying to make a prigramm that would dynamically put specific emojis over each of them. So that the number is behind it's emoji.

So far I've only managed to cross the numbers out on demand.
I was thinking, maybe there is a possibility to use emojis as a kind of a line-through-style in CSS?

UPD: So I I have `<i id="six">6</i>` in HTML and `#six::before {content: ''; position: absolute;}` in CSS, and it's working, although [it's displayed askew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ag0k.png), and `z-index` attribute doesnt change anything.

Comment: you may have dom elements intersecting each other when rendered in the viewport. Do you mean to just add an element on top of another? I ask because it's not clear how you wished to deal with the transparency and how the number below should appear. It's not clear also  what you meant by _line-through-style_, anyway as long as we are still talking of positioning, you could have a css rule using `::before` to set the content as the intended emoji, its `position absolute` and `z-index: 1` and trigger the class via js

Comment: Yes, one element over another, emoji over the number. Only the edges of the number should be visible.
Thanks, that could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of factors playing a role on why the content gets rendered with an offset relative to the container. The easiest approach to solve that is using an offset on the left property so that it gets aligned correctly.

I tried to make a demo extrapolating your initial conditions.

I used the `::before` pseudoelement to render the emoji content when a given class gets applied to the element. Anyway to make sure that the parent `<i>` element gets aligned with the pseudoelement, I styled it with fixed height and width and set the font size in the root element so that everything gets styled properly when using rem.

So this is the style for the .box element:

```
.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

`position:relative` is needed so that the pseudoelement will be positioned absolute relative to its parent; the size is fixed and the `display: inline-block` will make sure that the parent element will still be inline in terms of layout but will also take its width into consideration.

The demo has 3 buttons:

- One to toggle the emoji visibility
- One to toggle the box outline of the `<i>` elements (as red) and ::before elements (as blue)
- One to toggle the offset needed to better align the emoji content

I used `top: 20%` and I have to admit it was arbitrary. Anyway I'm quite sure it should scale well across font sizes.

One note aside, since the `<i>` element sets the formatting to italic, I changed it inside the pseudoelement (`font-style: normal;`) so that the emoji doesn't get stretched (like the flame you showed in your example).

To better show how this layout scales with font size I also added a range slider that will change the font size of the root element in real time.

```js
changeFontSize();

function toggleClassToBoxes(classname){
  document.querySelectorAll('.container > .box')
    .forEach(box => { box.classList.toggle(classname); });
}

function toggleClassToBoxesByNumber(classnamePrefix){
  document.querySelectorAll('.container > .box')
    .forEach(box => {
      const i = parseInt(box.textContent);
      const classname = `${classnamePrefix}-${i}`;
      box.classList.toggle(classname);
    });
}

function changeFontSize(range){
  if(!range)
    range = document.querySelector('.fontsize input');
  const value = `${range.value}px`;
  document.querySelector(':root').style.fontSize = value;
  document.querySelector('.fontsize label').textContent = `font-size: ${value};`;
}
```

```css
:root{
  font-size: 80px;
}

.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.box.outline{
  outline: solid red 6px;
}

.emoji::before {
  position: absolute;
  font-style: normal;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.emoji.outline::before {
  outline: solid blue 3px;
}

.emoji.offset::before {
  left: -20%;
  /*
  This was overstating for the sake of evaluating any option
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  */
}

.emoji-1::before{
  content: "";
}

.emoji-2::before{
  content: "";
}

.emoji-3::before{
  content: "";
}
.emoji-4::before{
  content: "";
}

.fontsize{
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.fontsize input{
  width: 50%;
}
button, input{
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}

label{
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <i class="box">1</i>
  <i class="box">2</i>
  <i class="box">3</i>
  <i class="box">4</i>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="buttonstripe">
    <button
      onclick="toggleClassToBoxes('emoji');toggleClassToBoxesByNumber('emoji');"
      >Toggle Emojis</button>
    <button onclick="toggleClassToBoxes('outline');">Toggle Outlines</button>
    <button onclick="toggleClassToBoxes('offset');">Toggle Offset</button>
  </div>
  <div class="fontsize">
    <input type="range" oninput="changeFontSize(this)" min="0" max="100" value="80">
    <label>font-size</label>
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to display an emoji involves simply copying and pasting. You just need an app or web site that allows you to copy emojis in their native, character form. One great place for doing that is Emojipedia. You can use Emojipedia to search or browse for whatever emoji you are looking for. Once you've found your emoji, there is a section where you can easily see and copy the emoji.

Comment: My problem is not displaying emojis, but displaying them OVER the elements

Comment: The answer is not addressing OPs problem.